# Alamofire response object mapping

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, alamofire, objectmapper

I am an android developer new to swift 3 programming, I am using [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) for making api calls and to avoid tedious json paring I am using [AlamofireObjectMapper](https://github.com/tristanhimmelman/AlamofireObjectMapper) library.
I have a `ApiController` which has a function to make api calls below is the code for that:

```
public static func makePostRequest<T: Mappable>(url: String, params: Parameters, networkProtocol: NetworkProtocol, responseClass: T){

    let headers = getHeaders()

    networkProtocol.showProgress()

    Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers)
        .validate()
        .responseData{ response in
            let json = response.result.value
            var jsonString = String(data: json!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
            let responseObject = responseClass(JSONString: jsonString!)
            switch(response.result){
            case .success(_):
                networkProtocol.hideProgress()
                networkProtocol.onResponse(response: response)
                break
            case .failure(_):
                networkProtocol.hideProgress()
                networkProtocol.onErrorResponse(response: response)
                break
            }

    }
```

The Json response template I am getting from server is:

```
{
 "some_int": 10, 
 "some_array":[...]
}
```

Below is my model class:

```
import ObjectMapper

    class BaseResponse: Mappable {
    var some_int: Int?
    var some_array: [Array_of_objects]?

    required init?(map: Map) {
        some_int <- map["some_int"]
        some_array <- map["some_array"]
    }

    func mapping(map: Map) {

    }
}
```

And below is the function to class make the api call:

```
public static func callSomeApi(params: Parameters, networkProtocol: NetworkProtocol){
    ApiHelper.makePostRequest(url: AppConstants.URLs.API_NAME, params: params, networkProtocol: networkProtocol, responseClass: BaseResponse)
}
```

Now the error is in the below line

```
let responseObject = responseClass(JSONString: jsonString!)
```

I am not able to understand how to convert `jsonString` into the `responseClass` generic object which I am accepting from View controller

Someone please help me resolve this, stuck on this issue for quite a while now.

Answer (score 4):

You can use AlamofireMapper:

With json:

```
{
   "page":1,
   "per_page":3,
   "total":12,
   "total_pages":4,
   "data":[
      {
         "id":1,
         "first_name":"George",
         "last_name":"Bluth",
         "avatar":"https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/calebogden/128.jpg"
      },
      {
         "id":2,
         "first_name":"Janet",
         "last_name":"Weaver",
         "avatar":"https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/josephstein/128.jpg"
      },
      {
         "id":3,
         "first_name":"Emma",
         "last_name":"Wong",
         "avatar":"https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/olegpogodaev/128.jpg"
      }
   ]
}
```

Swift class:

```
class UserResponse: Decodable {
    var page: Int!
    var per_page: Int!
    var total: Int!
    var total_pages: Int!

    var data: [User]?
}

class User: Decodable {
    var id: Double!
    var first_name: String!
    var last_name: String!
    var avatar: String!
}
```

Request with alamofire

```
let url1 = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sua8051/AlamofireMapper/master/user1.json"
        Alamofire.request(url1, method: .get
            , parameters: nil, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseObject { (response: DataResponse<UserResponse>) in
                switch response.result {
                case let .success(data):
                    dump(data)
                case let .failure(error):
                    dump(error)
                }
        }
```

Link: https://github.com/sua8051/AlamofireMapper

Answer (score 2):

### Generic Response Object Serialization using Swift 4 Codable

*If you don't want to use another dependency like ObjectMapper you can do the following way but you may have to make some chagnes.*

---

**Following** is a typical model which we use to deserialize JSON data with generics using Alamofire. There is plenty of examples and excellent [documentation](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/AdvancedUsage.md#generic-response-object-serialization) on Alamofire.

```
struct User: ResponseObjectSerializable, ResponseCollectionSerializable, CustomStringConvertible {
    let username: String
    let name: String

    var description: String {
        return "User: { username: \(username), name: \(name) }"
    }

    init?(response: HTTPURLResponse, representation: Any) {
        guard
            let username = response.url?.lastPathComponent,
            let representation = representation as? [String: Any],
            let name = representation["name"] as? String
        else { return nil }

        self.username = username
        self.name = name
    }
}
```

> Using Codable protocol introduced in Swift 4

```
typealias Codable = Decodable & Encodable
```

---

The first step in this direction is to add helper functions that
    will do half of the work in deserialization JSON data and handle
    errors. Using Swift extensions we add functions to decode incoming
    JSON into our model struct/class that we will write afterward.

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
let responseObject = try? decoder.decode(T.self, from: jsonData)
The decoder (1) is an object that decodes instances of a data type from JSON objects.
```

> Helper functions

```
extension DataRequest{
    /// @Returns - DataRequest
    /// completionHandler handles JSON Object T
    @discardableResult func responseObject<T: Decodable> (
        queue: DispatchQueue? = nil ,
        completionHandler: @escaping (DataResponse<T>) -> Void ) -> Self{

        let responseSerializer = DataResponseSerializer<T> { request, response, data, error in
            guard error == nil else {return .failure(BackendError.network(error: error!))}

            let result = DataRequest.serializeResponseData(response: response, data: data, error: error)
            guard case let .success(jsonData) = result else{
                return .failure(BackendError.jsonSerialization(error: result.error!))
            }

            // (1)- Json Decoder. Decodes the data object into expected type T
            // throws error when failes
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            guard let responseObject = try? decoder.decode(T.self, from: jsonData)else{
                return .failure(BackendError.objectSerialization(reason: "JSON object could not be serialized \(String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8)!)"))
            }
            return .success(responseObject)
        }
        return response(queue: queue, responseSerializer: responseSerializer, completionHandler: completionHandler)
    }

     /// @Returns - DataRequest
    /// completionHandler handles JSON Array [T]
    @discardableResult func responseCollection<T: Decodable>(
        queue: DispatchQueue? = nil, completionHandler: @escaping (DataResponse<[T]>) -> Void
        ) -> Self{

        let responseSerializer = DataResponseSerializer<[T]>{ request, response, data, error in
            guard error == nil else {return .failure(BackendError.network(error: error!))}

            let result = DataRequest.serializeResponseData(response: response, data: data, error: error)
            guard case let .success(jsonData) = result else{
                return .failure(BackendError.jsonSerialization(error: result.error!))
            }

            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            guard let responseArray = try? decoder.decode([T].self, from: jsonData)else{
                return .failure(BackendError.objectSerialization(reason: "JSON array could not be serialized \(String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8)!)"))
            }

            return .success(responseArray)
        }
        return response(responseSerializer: responseSerializer, completionHandler: completionHandler)
    }
 }
```

---

**Second**, I earlier mentioned “using Swift 4 Codable” but if all we
    want is to decode JSON from the server, we only need is a model
    struct/class that conforms to protocol Decodable. (If you have the
    same structure you want to upload you can use Codable to handle both
    decoding and encoding) So, now our User model struct now looks like
    this.

```
struct User: Decodable, CustomStringConvertible {
    let username: String
    let name: String

    /// This is the key part
    /// If parameters and variable name differ
    /// you can specify custom key for mapping "eg. 'user_name'"

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case username = "user_name"
        case name
    }

    var description: String {
        return "User: { username: \(username), name: \(name) }"
    }
}
```

---

**Lastly**, our function call to API looks like.

```
Alamofire.request(Router.readUser("mattt"))).responseObject{ (response: DataResponse<User>) in

            // Process userResponse, of type DataResponse<User>:
            if let user = response.value {
                print("User: { username: \(user.username), name: \(user.name) }")
            }
}
```

---

For more complex (nested) JSON, the logic remains the same and only modifications you need in model struct/class is that all structs/classes must conform to Decodable protocol and Swift takes care of everything else.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SwiftyJSON: https://cocoapods.org/pods/SwiftyJSON

Here is some example code could help you:

```
Alamofire.request(endpointURL, method: .get, parameters: params, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: nil).validate().responseJSON()
 {
        (response) in

        if response.result.isFailure
        {
            print("ERROR! Reverse geocoding failed!")
        }
        else if let value = response.result.value
        {
           var country: String? = nil
           var county: String? = nil
           var city: String? = nil
           var town: String? = nil
           var village: String? = nil

           print("data: \(value)")

           let json = JSON(value)

           print("json: \(json)")

           country = json["address"]["country"].string
           county = json["address"]["county"].string
           city = json["address"]["city"].string
           town = json["address"]["town"].string
           village = json["address"]["village"].string
        }
        else
        {
            print("Cannot get response result value!")
        }

 }
```

*Please let you know the code has been simplified (lot of line has been removed) and pasted here from my actual project, so this code is not tested, maybe contains typos or something like that, but the logic is* visible

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, my problem is I want to save the response in BaseResponse model class for which SwiftyJson won't help.

Comment: Ok, very sorry for my misunderstanding!

Answer (score 0):

For Object Mapping you need follow this with **AlamofireObjectMapper** .

```
//Declare this before ViewLoad
var BaseResponse: Array<BaseResponse>?

// After you receive response  from API lets say "data"
 if let jsonData = data as? String {
      self.BaseResponse = Mapper< BaseResponse >().mapArray(JSONString: jsonData)
}
```

Comment: The response is not an array it's just a json object.
{
 "some_int": 10
 "some_array":[...]
}

This is the template of Json response I am getting from server